# Rspec tests to voluntarily drop db connection

Tags: rspec, ruby-on-rails-5

We have a RoR 5 app which has threads created in its rails runner script. I need to test on how system behaves if the app drops off db connections(ActiveRecord, MYSQL database). This occurred in production and the app went to "unable to connect to mysql error" state . Manually, I can just reboot the db instance when the app is running and reproduce the scenario. I am trying to see if I can write a RSpec test for the same. Basically RSpec needs to access the app's database connection within the scope of the test and terminate it. Is that somehow possible in RSpec?